# Identifying unique notifications in StatusBarNotification object

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently using NotificationListenerService to log all the notifications received by phone.

The onNotificationPosted function of NotificationListenerService helps to receive all notifications, but the problem is sometimes it is getting called with the existing notifications. Is there any way or any property of StatusBarNotification object to identify the unique notification?

Here is my code.

```
class NotifyService : NotificationListenerService() {
    private val TAG = this.javaClass.simpleName
    var context: Context? = null
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = applicationContext
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        Log.i(TAG, "********** onNotificationPosted")

        Log.i(TAG,"${sbn.tag}_${sbn.id}_${sbn.packageName}_${sbn.postTime}")
        myListener?.setValue("Post: " + sbn.packageName)
    }

    fun setListener(myListener: MyListener?) {
        Companion.myListener = myListener
    }

    companion object {
        var myListener: MyListener? = null
    }
}
```